# Supplemental .config File example for adding a custom provider in siteMap

Tags: 2010, web-config

Microsoft provides the following [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms439965.aspx) for creating some actions in a web.config.

```
<actions>
   <add path="configuration/SharePoint/SafeControls">
      <SafeControl
         Assembly="System.Web, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, 
            PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"
         TypeName="*"
         Safe="True"/>
   </add>
   <remove path="configuration/SharePoint/RuntimeFilter"/>
   <add path="configuration/SharePoint">
      <RuntimeFilter
         Assembly="Company.Product, Version=1.0.1000.0, 
            Culture=neutral, PublickKeyToken=1111111111"
         Class="MyRuntTimeFilter",
         BuilderUrl="MyBuilderUrl"/>
   </add>
</actions>
```

I want to add something to:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="CurrentNavigation" enabled="true">
  <providers>
    <add name="SPNavigationProvider" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="SPSiteMapProvider" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="SPContentMapProvider" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPContentMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="SPXmlContentMapProvider" siteMapFile="_app_bin/layouts.sitemap" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPXmlContentMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="ExtendedSearchXmlContentMapProvider" description="Provider for navigation in Extended Search pages" siteMapFile="_app_bin/layouts.sitemap" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Extended.Administration.Common.ExtendedSearchXmlContentMapProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider" description="QuickLaunch navigation provider for the central administration site" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.AdministrationQuickLaunchProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server.UI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="SharedServicesQuickLaunchProvider" description="QuickLaunch navigation provider for shared services administration sites" type="Microsoft.Office.Server.Web.SharedServicesQuickLaunchProvider, Microsoft.Office.Server.UI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="GlobalNavSiteMapProvider" description="CMS provider for Global navigation" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Global" EncodeOutput="true" />
    <add name="CombinedNavSiteMapProvider" description="CMS provider for Combined navigation" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Combined" EncodeOutput="true" />
    <add name="CurrentNavSiteMapProvider" description="CMS provider for Current navigation" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Current" EncodeOutput="true" />
    <add name="CurrentNavSiteMapProviderNoEncode" description="CMS provider for Current navigation, no encoding of output" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Current" EncodeOutput="false" />
    <add name="GlobalNavigation" description="Provider for MOSS Global Navigation" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Combined" Version="14" />
    <add name="CurrentNavigation" description="Provider for MOSS Current Navigation" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Navigation.PortalSiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" NavigationType="Current" Version="14" />
    <add name="SiteDirectoryCategoryProvider" description="Site Directory category provider" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SiteDirectoryCategoryProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="MySiteMapProvider" description="MySite provider that returns areas and based on the current user context" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.MySiteMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="MySiteLeftNavProvider" description="MySite Left Nav provider that returns areas and based on the current user context" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.MySiteLeftNavProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <add name="MySiteSubNavProvider" description="MySite Sub Nav provider that returns areas and based on the current user context" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.MySiteSubNavProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

I have tried:

```
  <providers>
    <add name="JOHN" siteMapFile="john.xml" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPXmlContentMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  </providers>
```

and

```
<siteMap>
  <providers>
    <add name="JOHN" siteMapFile="john.xml" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPXmlContentMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

but my content is not being added. My file webconfig.john.xml is in the CONFIG folder. Running `stsadm -o copyappbincontent` is generating a new web.config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I have:

```
<add name="portalsitea_C3Management"
siteMapFile="/_app_bin/portalsitea/NLC3ManagementQuickLaunch.sitemap"
type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

I put my sitemaps in the _app_bin and they have a .sitemap extension. Note that I had some problems when I originally set this up because the sitemap file was not encoded properly with the text editor I was using. So make sure it is encoded properly.

Note also that I am using the XmlSiteMapProvider. You should be able to find plenty of documentation on it if you would rather use that.

Also, make sure you change the sitemapprovider on your master pages. If you need an example of that. Let me know.

Comment: If you could provide an example that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<actions>
  <add path="configuration/system.web/siteMap/providers">
 <add name="JOHN" siteMapFile="/_layouts/FeatureName/john.xml" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPXmlContentMapProvider, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
  </add>
</actions>
```

make sure you deploy your sitemap to the layouts\FeatureName folder.